# Limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(ax)}{\sqrt{bx+c^2}-c}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

How to find the following parametric limit without l' hospital rule?
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(ax)}{\sqrt{bx+c^2}-c}$$ with $$b>0$$

Comment: You want to assume $c > 0$.  $b > 0$ is not important.

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos That will not squeeze enough.  You need $\sin(ax) \sim a x$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: @Robert Israel, maybe $b\ne 0$ is important? Why is $c>0$ important?

Comment: If $c < 0$, $\sqrt{bx + c^2}$ would be near $-c$, not $c$.  Also $c=0$ would not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

For $x\neq 0$ we can put

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin (ax)}{\sqrt{bx+c^2}-c}&=\frac{\sin (ax)}{\sqrt{bx+c^2}-c}\cdot\frac{{\sqrt{bx+c^2}+c}}{\sqrt{bx+c^2}+c}\\
&=\frac{\sin (ax)}{bx}\cdot \left(\sqrt{bx+c^2}+c\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: But we still get the undefined form of $\frac{0}{0}$, right?

Answer (score 0):

Taylor series or equivalents are useful.

Consider first the denominator (assuming $c >0$) $$\sqrt{c^2+bx}-c=c \left(\sqrt{1+\frac b {c^2}x}-1 \right)$$ Now, use the generalized binomial theorem or Taylor series to get 
$$\sqrt{1+\frac b {c^2}x}=1+\frac{b }{2 c^2}x+O\left(x^2\right)$$ and $$\sin(ax)=ax+O\left(x^2\right)$$

I am sure that you can take it from here.